# ImageView doesn't shows above the recyclerView in same parent Layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingTop="5dip">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv_activity"
    android:elevation="2dp"
   android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/translation_selector"
    android:clickable="true">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_down"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_dk_grey_bg"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code. My imageView ivDown is not visible as the recylerView is overlapping. The image is not appearing on the screen, but all the elements for recyclerView adapter are getting displayed.
In the layout xml, the ivDown is visble, but after setting the adapter on my device it's not visible.
What should I do in this case??

Comment: the xml layout is correct share your activity code with question

Comment: You set the recyclerview to take the full space of the parent. Moreover, you set the imageview at the bottom of the parent

Comment: no problem in XML layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:elevation="2dp"` on `Recylerview` , which might cause your `Recycler` to overlap `imageview`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rv_activity"
   android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/translation_selector"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_down"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:background="@drawable/circular_dk_grey_bg"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    />
```

Comment: It shows the ivDown for few seconds and then it vanishes. I tried ivDown.brignToFront also, still not working

Comment: Updated the answer with elevation to imageview, try it once